# How to run the MVC 6 web app in Development environment when the web app is live

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an *ASP.Net MVC 6* (ASP 5, ASP vNext RC1) web application which I have deployed (published) on a test server (IIS 7.5) using *WebDeploy*.

When I run the application locally, the `IHostingEnvironment` parameter in the startup class is `env.EnvironmentName == "Development"`.

After publishing to the server, `env.EnvironemntName == "Production"`

**Question**

How can I change the application to run in the `Development` (or `Test`) environment after I have published it on the server?

In other words, I want the `env.EnvironmentName == "Development"` when the application is running on the IIS.

**Additional Information**

I have three application settings files: `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.development.json` and `appsettings.test.json`.

Each of these have different connection strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way would be setting system environment variable `ASPNET_ENV` to `Development` value. See [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html#development-staging-production) for additional information.

Comment: It's already set to `Development`.

Comment: @AliSharabiani: You should verify that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` really contains the key with the name `ASPNET_ENV` and the value `Development`.

Comment: So on the server, this key didn't exist,  I created it manually, and logged the value of the `env.EnvironmentName` to a file, it's still `Production`

Comment: @AliSharabiani: Sorry, but you should **not create the registry value manually** if you don't want to boot the server. Instead of that you should go to "Advanced" tab of "System Properties" (context menu on This PC) click "Environment Variables..." and then create new /modify existing in "System variables". The difference is: the Control Panel plugin send broadcast message to all windows, which inform about the changes on environment. You can now either create/modify some system Environment Variable or rebbot the server.

Comment: I created the environment variable in the System Properties, (both in user variables and system variables), I set the value to `Development`, `Staging` also checked the registry keys, everything is fine. However, when I publish the website, the application is still is running in `Production`.

Comment: @AliSharabiani: It can be that you have to restart IIS server. You can use [ProcessExplore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to examine Environment variables of IIS process. If you see that it has no `ASPNET_ENV` or it has it with old value then you can restart IIS and then verify Environment variables of IIS process once more.

Comment: I actually didn't restart the server. In IIS Application Pool I had to check `Load User Profile` to `True` so the environment variables could load. Thanks.

Comment: @AliSharabiani: You are welcome! It's good that you have found the reason.